# I need help formulating two simple triggers utilizing two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a Reorders table with the fields ProductID, ReorderAmount, and Reorder Date. I also have a table called Products with the fields ProductID, ProductName, ProductDesc, VendorID, QtyOnHand, ReorderLevel, and ReorderAmount.

What I want to create is a trigger that will create an entry in the Reorders table whenever the QtyOnHand from the Products table drops below the ReorderAmount, and of course checking to make sure an order hasn't already been placed. I then want another trigger that will delete entries from the Reorders table whenever the QtyOnHand rises above the ReorderAmount.

I've been looking up the syntax on how to do so, but I'm still pretty confused.
It appears as though I need to do...

```
CREATE TRIGGER trReorder ON Products /*Not sure if I should 
     use Reorders instead of Products*/

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Products WHERE QtyOnHand < ReorderAmount)

FOR
INSERT INTO Reorders
(ProductID, ReorderAmount, ReorderDate) VALUES (/*Not sure how to get
  it to pull the ProductID and ReorderAmount from the specific Product
  that was edited and how to get the current date*/)
```

I've seen a lot of different ways these are done, and I tried to follow the simplest one, but I'm not sure if I'm even heading in the right direction.

Any help is greatly appreciated! I'm also curious as to if once I figure out how to do the INSERT, if the DELETE is done similarly. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just whipped these up quickly, let me know if Ive missed anything.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trReorder]
   ON  [dbo].[Products]
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(  SELECT p.ProductID 
                FROM Products p 
                INNER JOIN inserted i 
                ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID
                WHERE p.ProductID = i.ProductID 
                AND p.QtyOnHand <= p.ReorderAmount)
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO dbo.Reorders
        SELECT p.ProductID, p.ReorderAmount, GETDATE()
        FROM Products p
        INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID
        WHERE p.ProductID = i.ProductID
        AND p.ProductID NOT IN (SELECT ProductID FROM dbo.Reorders)

    END

END


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trDelReorder]
   ON  [dbo].[Products]
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(  SELECT p.ProductID 
                FROM Products p 
                INNER JOIN inserted i 
                ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID
                WHERE p.ProductID = i.ProductID 
                AND p.QtyOnHand > p.ReorderAmount)
    BEGIN

        DELETE 
        FROM dbo.Reorders
        FROM dbo.Reorders r
        INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON r.ProductID = i.ProductID

    END

END
```

Comment: I ended up figuring out most of it, but it said I was using invalid column names. The inner join solved this problem! Thank you so much!